# Youngnuo 568iii off camera HSS

Tags: flash

I have got 568iii recently and not being able to set-up off camera high speed sync without the on camera flash. HHS works in Nikon’s commander mode with the built-in flash to trigger 568iii. Since I didn’t want to  depend on the on camera flash, I got a rf603n ii to communicate with flash. But HHS sign doesn’t come up  with the 603ii transmitters on when I go to higher shutter speed. Is there any way I can use the radio frequency to trigger HHS on 568iii with my current gears.( D750, youngnuo 568iii and rf603ii. )

Answer (score 1):

The Yongnuo RF603 series of transceivers do not offer High Speed Sync (HSS) functionality. So that eliminates what you want to do on the transmitter end.

The Yongnuo YN-568EX III flash does not have an internal radio receiver, so that eliminates using a radio transmitter without adding a radio receiver as well. But not just any radio transmitter/receiver set will do. You need one that supports Nikon's Auto FP (HSS).

The typical solution for using the YN-568EX III flashes to do off camera HSS is to use a YN622 set of triggers. The YN622 series supports HSS (and E-TTL, and several other things) that the manual-only RF603/RF605/YN560 radio protocol does not support. You can either use two YN622N transceivers, one serving as the transmitter on the camera and the other serving as the receiver attached to the flash's hot foot, or you can use a YN622N-TX (transmitter only, but with an LCD screen that makes it much easier to navigate the menu and set up multiple flash groups) on the camera with a YN622N receiver on your D750.

The latest versions of each:

- YN622N-TX
- YN622N II

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael.. I realized it later today when I used a Godoy transmitter and HSS worked fine. So if I would like new flash and what would you recommend for off camera HSS?